# Xamarin Android - Porting Android Api 26 --> API 28 - Button bring to front on click

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, migration, elevation

We are updating a Xamarin project from Android 8.0 to 9.0 (API 26 -> API 28).

We detect a different behavior on a layout: we have a button above which we display labels and icons inside a StackLayout.

With the old Android 8.0 version, we could correctly click on the button.
With the new Android 9.0 version, we note that we can correctly click on the button, but when we click the button is brought to the front and hides the StackLayout labels and icons.
When we return to this screen, the button remains in the foreground and the StackLayout labels and icons no longer appear.

How can we force the StackLayout labels and icons to stay on the button even if the button is clicked?
Thanks

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <ctrl:TitleBarControl x:Name="titleBar" Title="Menu Trasporto Valori"></ctrl:TitleBarControl>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource standardGrid}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="btnProssimo" Image="MondoConPinPoint_48x48.gif" Text="Prossimo" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Command="{Binding ProssimoCommand}"></Button>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End">
                <Label Text="Da eseguire:" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  Style="{StaticResource lightLabel}"></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding DaEseguire}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource boldLabel}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <Button x:Name="btnProssimoI" Image="Cacciavite_48x48.gif" Text="Prossimo I" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Command="{Binding ProssimoICommand}"></Button>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End">
                <Label Text="Da eseguire:" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource lightLabel}"></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding IDaEseguire}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource boldLabel}"></Label>
                <Image x:Name="imgSveglia" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End" Source="Sveglia_24x24.gif" WidthRequest="26" IsVisible="{Binding IsI}"></Image>
            </StackLayout>


        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from Xamarin.Forms 4.0 onwards, all applications targeting `FormsAppCompatActivity` will use the Fast Renderers by default.
If you want to workaround this issue, you can disable the FastRenderers. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/fast-renderers#backwards-compatibility

add the following to your `MainActivity.OnCreate` before the `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState)`  call:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");
```

Comment: Thanks Leo Zhu, your indication solves the problem.
However, I still have a doubt: does the "UseLegacyRenderers" flag ensure that the same effects are obtained as with the Xamarin.Forms versions prior to 4.0?
I would like to understand indicatively the impact of this flag on the entire project.

Comment: yes,the effects are the same.Functionally, these fast renderers are no different to the legacy renderers.

Comment: One last question: is it possible to modify the rendering of a single specific view?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand: if I wanted to simply adopt the old default renderer (the not-fast "Legacy") in a single view and adopt the new standard fast renderers in all other views, should I still create my own custom renderer?

Comment: if you want to use old default renderer,you just need add `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");`,

Comment: I would not recommend to disable fast renderers at all but if you really want it then use a custom renderer for the specific control.

Answer (score 0):

Please use an `ImageButton` instead. This should solve your problem.